# How to make long Bootstrap dropdown menus vertically scrollable?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got the following responsive site to work the way I want it on all devices. The only remaining problem is **to make the drop down menu scrollable** so that when the number of options in the dropdown menu is more than can fit on the device's screen, there is a way to scroll it.

These dropdown menus used to scroll during development of this as in this example (http://tanguay.info/testmenu2). But since I needed to add fixed heights etc. to get this design the way it is, it has many these these dropdown menus unscrollable. **How can I get this scrollable functionality back while keeping the current functionality of the site, i.e. with footer that stays in place?**

Here is how it looks in Smartphone and Computer views:

**Smartphone:**
[image]

**Computer:**
[image]

You can view this test site here: http://tanguay.info/testmenu

You can download the code here: http://tanguay.info/testmenu/testmenu.zip

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/bootstrap_custom_extensions.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/bootstrap_override.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/system_navbarResponsiveSite.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/system_reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/system_developer.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/system_main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/custom_main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_fichiers/lt.css">
        <script src="index_fichiers/jquery-2.js"></script>
        <script src="index_fichiers/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="index_fichiers/qtools.js"></script>
        <script src="index_fichiers/system_main.js"></script>
        <script src="index_fichiers/angular.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*  page-level CSS */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">                    
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                        <div class="navHeaderArea">
                            <div class="theUser" onclick="location.href = '?';">The Test Site</div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown pull-right active">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">MENU</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #7</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #8</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #9</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #10</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #11</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #13</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #14</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #15</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #16</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #17</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #18</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #19</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Test Page #20</a></li>
                            </ul>                            
                        </li>
                    </ul>                
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="pageContent"><div ng-app="mainModule" ng-controller="mainController" class="angular-hide-during-page-load ng-scope">
                    <h1 class="showcaseTitle">Test Page</h1>
                    <div class="showcaseDescription">This is a test page that shows how the menu extends to far past the bottom of the screen.</div>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading ng-binding">Input Text</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <div>line #0</div><div>line #1</div><div>line #2</div><div>line #3</div><div>line #4</div><div>line #5</div><div>line #6</div><div>line #7</div><div>line #8</div><div>line #9</div><div>line #10</div><div>line #11</div><div>line #12</div><div>line #13</div><div>line #14</div><div>line #15</div><div>line #16</div><div>line #17</div><div>line #18</div><div>line #19</div><div>line #20</div><div>line #21</div><div>line #22</div><div>line #23</div><div>line #24</div><div>line #25</div><div>line #26</div><div>line #27</div><div>line #28</div><div>line #29</div><div>line #30</div><div>line #31</div><div>line #32</div><div>line #33</div><div>line #34</div><div>line #35</div><div>line #36</div><div>line #37</div><div>line #38</div><div>line #39</div><div>line #40</div><div>line #41</div><div>line #42</div><div>line #43</div><div>line #44</div><div>line #45</div><div>line #46</div><div>line #47</div><div>line #48</div><div>line #49</div><div>line #50</div><div>line #51</div><div>line #52</div><div>line #53</div><div>line #54</div><div>line #55</div><div>line #56</div><div>line #57</div><div>line #58</div><div>line #59</div><div>line #60</div><div>line #61</div><div>line #62</div><div>line #63</div><div>line #64</div><div>line #65</div><div>line #66</div><div>line #67</div><div>line #68</div><div>line #69</div><div>line #70</div><div>line #71</div><div>line #72</div><div>line #73</div><div>line #74</div><div>line #75</div><div>line #76</div><div>line #77</div><div>line #78</div><div>line #79</div><div>line #80</div><div>line #81</div><div>line #82</div><div>line #83</div><div>line #84</div><div>line #85</div><div>line #86</div><div>line #87</div><div>line #88</div><div>line #89</div><div>line #90</div><div>line #91</div><div>line #92</div><div>line #93</div><div>line #94</div><div>line #95</div><div>line #96</div><div>line #97</div><div>line #98</div><div>line #99</div><div>line #100</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pageFooter">
                <div class="page_Footer_left">The Footer</div>
                <div class="page_Footer_right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this by specifying `max-height` and `overflow-y` on the dropdown:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

You can calculate the max-height in JS or use viewport units. For example, if you want your dropdown to fill the space up until the bottom of the page, you could use: `max-height: calc(100vh - 50px)`, where 50px is the height of your header.

Note that in the above solution the list on the left will not be scrolled independently of the dropdown. Once you reach the end of the dropdown, it will continue scrolling the list. 
To prevent this, make the panel overflow as well:

```
.panel.panel-primary{
    max-height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Again, it depends on your use case on how to go about to calculate the max heights.

Comment: Thanks, the `max-height: calc(100vh - 50px)` and `overflow-y:auto` works perfectly in every device I've tested it in on, only displaying a scrollbar when needed for that device height: http://tanguay.info/testmenu4

Comment: This solution works great, unless you have sub-menus. Since sub-menus are nested inside the `.dropdown-menu` having a sub-menu triggers showing a horizontal scrollbar and is displayed INSIDE the parent menu. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nupkc/mrhofge4/)

Answer (score 3):

it will be scrollable when the outer container has fixed height and has `overflow:scroll`  or `overflow:auto` in css

so `.dropdown-menu` for mobile devices should have a fixed height depending on screen height. it can be achieved using css property viewport height( this will chage with device) `max-height:80vh`(change this depending on ur requirement). look into it.

so add `overflow:auto` and `max-height:80vh` to `.dropdown-menu` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
.dropdown-menu
 {
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

The `max-height` property limits the maximum height.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice, simple solution and looks fine and has good user functionality in my smart phone browser and ipad emulators: http://tanguay.info/testmenu3

Comment: Use `overflow-y: auto` rather than `overflow-y: scroll`. The latter will show scrollbars even when the element is not overflowing (except on Apple devices, where scrollbars are never shown).

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this with just adding pre-scrollable in `ul` tag:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable">
```

Comment: Just to note, `pre-scrollable` will show the scrollbars at all times (at least on Chrome), it's not a great look